# Can MSVC 2013 inline calls into x64 assembly code from a separate object file?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, assembly, compiler-optimization, inlining

I'm learning x64 assembly on MSVC.  Inline assembly is not allowed in x64 code.  I wrote an extremely simple floating-point function in a separate file:

```
.data
TWO_DOUBLE real8 2.0

.code
mul2 proc
    movsd xmm1, TWO_DOUBLE
    mulsd xmm0, xmm1
    ret 
mul2 endp
```

Then I called my function from C++:

```
extern "C" double mul2(double x);

int main()
{
    double d2 = mul2(1.0);
}
```

Compiling in Release mode, `/O2` optimized and `/LTCG` enabled, my disassembled executable looks like this:

```
<addr> movsd  xmm0, mmword ptr [__real@3ff0000000000000 (013F9F21A8h)]  
<addr> call   mul2 (013F9F1075h)
```

However, if I write the same function in C++, it gets converted into a single inline `mulsd` instruction.

*(Actually, I had to return the result from `main` to avoid making the whole program a no-op, and randomize the input variable to keep the compiler from calculating the result at compile time.)*

This seems like a pretty serious flaw for a programmer who wishes to optimize her code with hand-written assembly.  If MSVC can't inline it, then it's probably not worth the function call overhead unless you do a significant amount of work in the assembly.

Is there some way to get MSVC to inline hand-written assembly that I'm missing?

edit: I'm aware that a more complex assembly function that uses the stack might be more difficult to inline, but something simple that only uses volatile registers should be really easy... right?

Comment: As Igor says, use intrinsics, not assembly, to access the specialized instructions.

Comment: OK my example was bad because I used `xmm` registers to do plain' old scalar FP, as is standard for x64.  MSVC's generated x64 FP code is full of SSE scalar instructions so I wouldn't really call them "specialized". I should have used integer math in my example to avoid this misunderstanding.

Comment: For "simple" instructions that don't have intrinsic functions, just write normal C++ code.  If you use an assembler style (one operation per line, compound assignment so the result goes back to the operand register), then you can pretty well control the assembly which is generated prior to optimization.  After optimization it may differ, but that's what you wanted (for a function call not to generate a CALL instruction).

Comment: Yeah I know.  This was a theoretical question about MSVC's capabilities.  I'm not using hand written assembler in any real projects and I am always able to get the desired assembly output by tweaking c++ code.  Thank you for your answers though, I agree with everything you said in a real world setting.

Answer (score 3):

For WPO (whole program optimization) to apply cross-module inlining, *both* the calling and called modules must be compiled with `/LTGC`.

`/LTGC` produces not final binary code, but special object files with intermediate language (CIL) in them. Since your assembly is already machine code, it cannot participate in WPO and thus cannot be inlined.

If you want to use SIMD instructions but still take advantage of WPO, you can use [compiler intrinsics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x8zs5twb) instead of assembly. For example, `mulsd` corresponds to [`_mm_mul_sd`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch4zxs9x).

Comment: I understand how WPO works - I thought it might be possible for the compiler to represent user-written ASM in its IL.

Comment: For that it would basically have to decompile everything back to IL. Too much work for uncertain return. Also, usually the users who write assembler snippets want them to **stay as is** and not be mangled/reordered by the compiler (which would happen at the IL optimization step).